# how to control canvas bitmap with my button on mainactivity?

Tags: android, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-button, bitmapfactory

I already have x and y variables on surfaceview but don't know how to accsess them from
my main activity where my button stays.

This looks like a million dollar question no one answers me I've posted this question several times and I cant find anything related to this.

here is the button:

```
 Button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {


//I want to access variable x and y of surfaceview


             if (x==230)
            x=x +20;

        invalidate();

    }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've created a subclass of `SurfaceView` where you have your x and y variables, best practice would be to create setters and getters for those variables (I'm calling it `setPositionX()` instead of `setX()`, because `SurfaceView` already has that method):

```
public class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView {
    private int x;

    private int y;

    public void setPositionX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getPositionX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getPositionY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

and in your Activity:

```
private MySurfaceView mySurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create SurfaceView and assign it to a variable.
    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);

    // Do other initialization. Create button listener and other stuff.
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    int x = mySurfaceView.getPositionX();
    int y = mySurfaceView.getPositionY();

    if (x == 230) {
        mySurfaceView.setPositionX(x + 20);
    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an interface? Once you get the x and y values you can pass them to an interface method. Then you can implement that interface on your MainActivity.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff some examples would be appreciated

Comment: Also, it may be easier if you make the variables public and static so they can be access from anywhere. The benefit of using an interface is that it acts as a listener. The flow of execution will go back to the calling Class. Here you can find how to define an interface. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm